# Parsing a Tuple (String,Int) in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, tuples, monads, parsec

I  need to parse a `(String,Int)` type as `userRatings` is in order to read from a `textFile` correctly and I am using `Parsec`. This is the Parsing along with the import, my `stringInt` tuple function has this error.

> Expecting two more arguments to ‘Parsec (String, Int)’
>       Expected a type, but ‘Parsec (String, Int)’ has kind ‘* -> * -> *’
>       In the type signature for ‘stringIntTuple’:
>         stringIntTuple :: Parsec (String, Int)

```
    import Control.Monad
    import Control.Applicative((<*))
    import Text.Parsec
        ( Parsec, ParseError, parse        -- Types and parser
        , between, noneOf, sepBy, many1    -- Combinators
        , char, spaces, digit, newline     -- Simple parsers
        )
    -- Types
    type Title = String
    type Director = String
    type Year = Int
    type UserRatings = (String,Int) 
    type Film = (Title, Director, Year , [UserRatings])
    type Period = (Year, Year)
    type Database = [Film]


    -- Parse a string to a string
    stringLit :: Parsec String u String
    stringLit = between (char '"') (char '"') $ many1 $ noneOf "\"\n"

    -- Parse a string to a list of strings
   listOfStrings :: Parsec String u [String]
   listOfStrings = stringLit `sepBy` (char ',' >> spaces)

   -- Parse a string to an int
   intLit :: Parsec String u Int
   intLit = fmap read $ many1 digit
   -- Or `read <$> many1 digit` with Control.Applicative
   stringIntTuple :: Parsec (String , Int)
   stringIntTuple = liftM2 (,) stringLit intLit

   film :: Parsec String u Film
   film = do

title <- stringLit
newline
director <- stringLit
newline
year <- intLit
newline
userRatings <- stringIntTuple
newline
return (title, director, year, userRatings)
```

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times. Stack Overflow has mechanisms to attract attention to an existing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is basically saying that you did not supply enough type arguments. And if you compare the signature of your tuple parser with the others you'll see why:

```
stringLit :: Parsec String u String
listOfStrings :: Parsec String u [String]
stringIntTuple :: Parsec (String , Int)
```

In all other cases you supply three type arguments, but for `stringIntTuple` you only supply one.

So just add `String` and `u` as the first two arguments, like you did for the others, and it'll work.

Comment: thank you! so obvious though :P